# Count the number of items in a TListview Group

Tags: delphi, tlistview

When I attempt to count the number of items in a group I get the total number of items in the collection.  How do you get the number of items in each group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the simplest way.

```
procedure TForm1.Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetNumItemsInGroup(1)));
end;

function TForm1.GetNumItemsInGroup(const GroupID: integer): integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  assert((GroupID >= 0) and (GroupID <= ListView1.Groups.Count - 1));
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
    if ListView1.Items.Item[i].GroupID = GroupID then
      inc(result);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Under Vista and later only, the `LVM_GETGROUPINFO` and `LVM_GETGROUPINFOBYINDEX` messages return a LVGROUP structure that has a `cItems` member specifying the number of items in the group.

Comment: This is a much better solution. In particular, it is likely much faster in very large list views. However, in my experience, list view groups don't work well at all with large amounts of data, so this difference might not matter much in practice...